# Extract the Lift and Support from Association Rules using SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using the Frequent Pattern Mining algorithm - Association Rules:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset

val freqItemsets = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  new FreqItemset(Array("a"), 15L),
  new FreqItemset(Array("b"), 35L),
  new FreqItemset(Array("a", "b"), 12L)
))

val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)
val results = ar.run(freqItemsets)

results.collect().foreach { rule =>
  println("[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",")
    + "=>"
    + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence)
}
```

Is possible to extract the Support and the Lift of the Rule? I'm only getting the confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currenlty no.
There are two JIRA ticket for it.

See:

- ### About Lift [SPARK-10697](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10697)

> Adding Lift Calculation in Association Rule mining

- ### About Support [SPARK-15938](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15938)

> Adding Support Calculation in Association Rule mining

Comment: Hi @Umberto, many thanks for your response. :) I'm not understanding very well how can I apply this on Spark. Is this an API?

Comment: Hi @João_testeSW you are welcome :). When they are ready you can use It with the methods **rule.support** and **rule.lift**